# Why do typescript infer indexing with a generic into an intersection rather than a union?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following variables and types:

```
export type IPage = {
    title: string;
};

export type IArticle = {
    title: string;
    body: string;
};

export type PageTypesMap = {
    'page': IPage;
    'article': IArticle;
};

export const pageContentTypesEndpoints = {
    'page': 'pages',
    'article': 'articles',
} as const;

export type PageTypesWithContentType = {
    [key in keyof PageTypesMap]: PageTypesMap[key] & { __contentType: key };
};

export type PageTypes = {
    [key in keyof PageTypesMap]: PageTypesMap[key];
};
```

If I use `PageTypesWithContentType['api::page.page' | 'api::article.article']` I get a union of the types as expected, but something very strange happens if I use a generic function and tries to do the same:

```
const setContentType = <ContentType extends keyof typeof pageContentTypesEndpoints>(
    page: PageTypes[ContentType],
    contentType: ContentType
): PageTypesWithContentType[ContentType] => {
    const result: PageTypesWithContentType[ContentType] = {
        ...page,
        __contentType: contentType,
    };
    return result;
};
```

This gives an error on the result variable

```
Type 'PageTypes[ContentType] & { __contentType: ContentType; }' is not assignable to type 'PageTypesWithContentType[ContentType]'.
  Type 'PageTypes[ContentType] & { __contentType: ContentType; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
    The intersection 'IPage & { __contentType: "page"; } & IArticle & { __contentType: "article"; }' was reduced to 'never' because property '__contentType' has conflicting types in some constituents.
```

The thing that confuses me the most is that it creates an intersection (`IPage & { __contentType: "api::page.page"; } & IArticle & { __contentType: "api::article.article"; }`) instead of a union. Why does this happen?

Even if I try setting the generic `ContentType` to extend `'api::page.page' | 'api::article.article'`, it gives the same error.

EDIT:

Check it out here, you can't see the error here, but you can fork it and see the error in the editor: https://replit.com/@Alexnortung/ForsakenThunderousLocation#index.ts

Comment: Thanks for the reply @jcalz I have modified the code and provided a link to repl.it

Comment: When you do an assignment across indexed access types, the compiler will often not be able to tell that the indexes are correlated and it will fall back to safe-but-annoying behavior described in [ms/TS#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), which is where that intersection comes from. The only way I know how to resolve this (without type assertions) involves a *distributive object type* as described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) which looks like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WPB2EN).

Comment: (See prev comment).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeScript 3.5 [introduced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-3-5/#fixes-to-unsound-writes-to-indexed-access-types) a type safety improvement, as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#30769](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/30769), to prevent unsafe assignments to [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).  If you read a value from an indexed access like

```
const obj = { a: { x: 1 }, b: { y: 2 } };
const key = Math.random() < 0.5 ? "a" : "b"
const val = obj[key]; // { x: number } | { y: number }
```

where the key is a [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `"a" | "b"`, then the type of `val` will also be a union type like `{x: number} | {y: number}`.  But if you *write* a value to an indexed access type like

```
obj[k] = ❓❓;
```

then what type can that value be?  In order to be safe, it can't be the union `{x: number} | {y: number}`, because this will let you assign a `{x: number}` value to a `{y: number}` property or vice versa.  The only safe thing is the [*intersection*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types)  `{x: number} & {y: number}` (a.k.a. `{x: number; y: number}`).  And that's what TypeScript enforces:

```
obj[key] = { x: 2 }; // error!
// Type '{ x: number; }' is not assignable to type 
// '{ x: number; } & { y: number; }'.

obj[key] = { x: 2, y: 3 }; // okay
```

Unfortunately this ends up being *too* safe sometimes.  The compiler only tracks keys by their *type* and not their *identity*.  If you have two different variables `key1` and `key2` both of a union type then

```
obj[key2] = obj[key1]; // error!
```

is definitely unsafe.  But the compiler can't tell the difference between that and the *obviously acceptable* version:

```
obj[key] = obj[key]; // still error!
// Type '{ x: number; } | { y: number; }' is not assignable 
// to type '{ x: number; } & { y: number; }'.
```

The compiler thinks that's unsafe because it doesn't know that the key will be the same on both sides of the assignment.  That is, it doesn't understand that both sides of the assignment are *correlated*.  This is the topic of [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581)

So while microsoft/TypeScript#30769 prevented some bad assignments, it has also, unfortunately, prevented some good ones.

---

The problem you're facing your code is essentially fallout from this.  You're not using a union-typed value directly, but a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html)-typed value whose generic type is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to a union.  But the behavior can be the same; unless the compiler has some way to follow the correlated generic operation, it will tend to evaluate such values by widening them to the union constraint, and you get the same error:

```
const setContentType = <K extends keyof PageTypes>(
    page: PageTypes[K],
    contentType: K
): PageTypesWithContentType[K] => {
    const result: PageTypesWithContentType[K] = {
        ...page,
        __contentType: contentType,
    }; // error!
    // Type 'PageTypes[K] & { __contentType: K; }' is not assignable to 
    // type 'IPage & { __contentType: "page"; } & 
    //       IArticle & { __contentType: "article"; }'
    return result;
};
```

The compiler has lost track of what you're doing, and is therefore insisting that the only safe thing to assign to `PageTypesWithContentType[K]` is the *intersection* of that type for every possible `K`.  And since that would result in conflicting `__contentType` properties, that reduces to [the impossible `never` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-never-type).  So basically it says that no such assignment is safe.

---

The only way I know to fix this is to refactor to express the operations in a particular way as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The code implemented there was specifically introduced to allow some way to deal with correlated union types.  The refactoring is generally to write everything in terms of a very basic key-value interface type, and generic indexes into that type or mapped types over that type.  In particular it introduces the concept of a *distributive object type* of the form:

```
type DistribObj<K extends keyof Base> = {[P in K]: F<P>}[K]
```

which, when `K` is a union type like `K1 | K2 | K3`, produces a union output like `F<K1> | F<K2> | F<K3>`.  (So the `F<>` operation is *distributed* across unions in `K`.)  Distributive object types are more amenable to the compiler's analysis than equivalent non-distributive types.

For your code the change looks like:

```
type PageTypeWithContentType<K extends keyof PageTypes> = {
    [P in K]: PageTypes[P] & { __contentType: P }
}[K]

const setContentType = <K extends keyof PageTypes>(
    page: PageTypes[K],
    contentType: K
): PageTypeWithContentType<K> => {
    const result = {
        ...page,
        __contentType: contentType,
    };  
    return result; // okay
};
```

So instead of `PageTypesWithContentType[K]`, we write `PageTypeWithContentType<K>`.  But otherwise it's the same.  And indeed for all the use cases you care about, all the types are equivalent in both versions.  But the compiler "understands" the distributive object type in the way it does not with the original form.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=87&ssc=1&pln=77&pc=1#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-MsLM5vOj8fpXHLfBEUiyGWWyMQZsAdW1OlrjYbTctvb7SHiAGkZsAkEkCAAzCNp5vJFg75s30rspAAfX-BR60baMWFvM1l03dIK3dCASGPECzzRehbFvCBWBAkw5kfF8v0OKAAD4LAnKtPzfAifyXS9gNPMCkGvAorHIqMCIPXRELow4fzoQjpUvNdFCQAxoCGKISBY3c2MPTjQO468oX4gS8D0VSq2o5SAKAusuJ6FhaLknoNI1SDLwyAAqTpLV6fCeigHi-0AgzkIgcCeTJeZFkYKkNhALYdnpazgAgcJ6l5dIOh0ZAu3qKAIHgLUiHRVMVSuBgnJ0wzXK8KtPDZQt51pRztJPLL-CnXNtjy0lzIyCcRJIIYDHvESoDEkhS03PkBSFaA4EQJAAHECD9JTcHDFLVTGjUtR1bLAy9KDQ3Gy0bUKqb1UvWa3QWjMfT9AMSANIMCjLC00VsmMLz7YcZytHc9vjCq8wLNbp065bBLCKtZJc1t207Rse2mzMqyHKtFwnOdpyHZ7tkh5dvK+jrPvDS72KPTKXLQpAMKwnDVGfV9WLsvjro1eIFTvBiP2JqS7Mp390pKpD6Kp-llx-T7YLihCsejdQcbxhtsIfQm8Io0mSIEsi6e-BTjJg-nDnApjJOjDHfujNCyb4za+1g1r2tjTTcFUvR1IndIMtKlz9OVoyJ1MvsGqalrRPEj6+SAA)